# Accessing external storage from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver (Android 4.1) which must test for the existence of a file located in the external storage area. The receiver doesn't need to read or write to the file; just test for its existence.

I haven't found anything in the Android documentation which indicates that BroadcastReceivers cannot access external files, yet the code below always returns false.

The logcat output shows getExternalStorageState() returns "mounted" and I can access the file using an ordinary App, just not in the Receiver. No exceptions are thrown.

```
public class FileCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean b = checkFile();
        Log.d(TAG, "FileCheckReceiver: " + b);
    }

    boolean checkFile() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        Log.d(TAG, "FileCheckReceiver, Environment.getExternalStorageState: " + state);
        String name = "file.txt";
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + name);
        try
        {
            if (f.exists()) {
                System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath().toString());
                return true;
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Are BroadcastReceivers stopped from accessing files?

Comment: What permissions do you have in your manifest?

Comment: @Flynn81 I have the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED (for the broadcast intent) and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions declared in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would to be start a new Service from the BroadcastReceiver to handle tasks that you wish to perform.

Other things:

1. Make sure you have declared the receiver in manifest.xml
2. Also you need to consider the following as well.

> As of Android 3.1 the Android system will by default exclude all BroadcastReceiver from receiving intents if the corresponding application has never been started by the user or if the user explicitly stopped the application via the Android menu (in Manage Application).
>
> This is an additional security features as the user can be sure that only the applications he started will receive broadcast intents.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually discovered that System Apps (which my app was) do not have any access to files stored on external storage.

Moving my BroadcastReceiver to another (non-system) APK fixed the problem.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? This does not seem right at all to me. I'm curious what version of AOSP you were using at the time, and what error you got.